# Question about "ほう" in this context

Tags: meaning

Heres the sentence :

> 彼は自由なほうの手を伸ばして頭皮をさわり、痛みの源を突き止めようとした。

So I understand the sentence, I think, by context, as :
"He reached up with his free arm and touched his scalp, trying to determine the origin of his headache."

But i can't find a good definition or explanation for this "ほう", which kanji is this related ? what's the meaning here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kanji that's it's representing is the standard 方. It is used in the standard way of making a comparison between two objects. Here the comparison is between the two hands of the person. As for what comparison it's making, the answer is that it's comparing the 自由-ness of the two hands. So here 自由なほうの手 means the hand that is more 自由.

Edit: As [Chocolate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9831/chocolate) points out, 方 when used here isn't actually making a comparison between the **level** of 自由, but the **existence** of 自由 or not.

Comment: `making a comparison between two objects.` `it's comparing the 自由-ness` `自由なほうの手 means the hand that is more 自由.` -- それは「二者を取り上げて比較した時の一方。 『兄より弟の方が背が高い』」（大辞林）の用法ですよね。ここでの「自由な方の手を伸ばして…」の「方」は、「対立的に存在するものの一方。がわ。 」(大辞林) の用法ですよね。「2本ある手を比較して、比較的、より自由な方の手 (the *more* free hand between the two hands)」って意味じゃなくて、「自由な手と自由でない手があって、その自由な方の手(the free hand, not the other not-free hand)」(「自由なほうの手」というからには、「自由でない手」が存在する)ですよね。

Comment: @Chocolate そうなんですか？確かに、その用法はもっと合うよね。指摘してくれてありがとう！